# Why UNION result not appearing at bottom?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

Initially I was working with two query,
One was returning Student's marks,
second was returning Grand Total Marks.

Now I decided to Union these two queries but my Grand Total row is appearing at top, which I want at bottom, I tried changing the sequencing of two, but no impact on result. Please suggest, my query is:

```
SELECT AISECTRESULT_Schemes.SUBNO, 
        AISECTRESULT_Schemes.SUBJECT, 
        AISECTRESULT_Schemes.CE_TotalMarks, 
        AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.TotalMarksObt_C, 
        AISECTRESULT_Schemes.TE_TotalMarks, 
        AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.TotalMarksObt,
        MAXMARKS, 
        AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.OverAllMarks 
  FROM AISECTRESULT_Schemes 
 INNER JOIN AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData 
    ON AISECTRESULT_Schemes.[EXAMSCHEME ID] = AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.EXAMSCHEMEID
 WHERE (AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.REGISTRATIONID = '201192145')

UNION

SELECT ''AS SUBNO,
       ''AS SUBJECT,
        SUM(AISECTRESULT_Schemes.CE_TotalMarks)CE_TotalMarks, 
        SUM(AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.TotalMarksObt_C)TotalMarksObt_C,
        SUM(AISECTRESULT_Schemes.TE_TotalMarks)TE_TotalMarks, 
        SUM(AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.TotalMarksObt)TotalMarksObt,
        SUM(AISECTRESULT_Schemes.MAXMARKS)MAXMARKS,
        SUM(AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.OverAllMarks)OverAllMarks
  FROM AISECTRESULT_Schemes
 INNER JOIN AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData
    ON AISECTRESULT_Schemes.[EXAMSCHEME ID] = AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.EXAMSCHEMEID
 WHERE (AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.REGISTRATIONID = '201192145')
```

[image]

Comment: For what database?  A little formatting to make the query readable might help.

Comment: The top component has 8 fields in `SELECT` while the bottom has 7 that I count.

Comment: @Michael - I see the same number of columns on both

Comment: @michael, No  Michael, both query has 8 columns, because of my image path you are not able to see 8th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `ORDER BY` on your query. This should do it:

```
SELECT  SUBNO, 
        SUBJECT, 
        CE_TotalMarks, 
        TotalMarksObt_C, 
        TE_TotalMarks, 
        TotalMarksObt,
        MAXMARKS, 
        OverAllMark
FROM (  SELECT  AISECTRESULT_Schemes.SUBNO, 
                AISECTRESULT_Schemes.SUBJECT, 
                AISECTRESULT_Schemes.CE_TotalMarks, 
                AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.TotalMarksObt_C, 
                AISECTRESULT_Schemes.TE_TotalMarks, 
                AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.TotalMarksObt,
                MAXMARKS, 
                AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.OverAllMarks,
                1 ColOrder
        FROM AISECTRESULT_Schemes 
        INNER JOIN AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData 
        ON AISECTRESULT_Schemes.[EXAMSCHEME ID] = AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.EXAMSCHEMEID
        WHERE AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.REGISTRATIONID = '201192145'

        UNION

        SELECT  ''AS SUBNO,''AS SUBJECT,
                SUM(AISECTRESULT_Schemes.CE_TotalMarks)CE_TotalMarks, 
                SUM(AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.TotalMarksObt_C)TotalMarksObt_C,
                SUM(AISECTRESULT_Schemes.TE_TotalMarks)TE_TotalMarks, 
                SUM(AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.TotalMarksObt)TotalMarksObt,
                SUM(AISECTRESULT_Schemes.MAXMARKS)MAXMARKS,
                SUM(AISECTRESULT_Exa![enter image description here][1]mMarksData.OverAllMarks)OverAllMarks,
                2
        FROM AISECTRESULT_Schemes 
        INNER JOIN AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData 
        ON AISECTRESULT_Schemes.[EXAMSCHEME ID] = AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.EXAMSCHEMEID 
        WHERE AISECTRESULT_ExamMarksData.REGISTRATIONID = '201192145') AS Data
ORDER BY ColOrder
```

Comment: @AjitD - Its exactly as @Lieven said on his answer. I took your query and used it as a derived table, but first I added a column with the sort order. Then I added an `ORDER BY` at the end of the query

Answer (score 4):

The ordering of results of a query is arbitrary without an **explicit** `ORDER BY`.

Now you might notice that the ordering always **seems** to be the same but rest assure: adding data or changing clustered indexes or whatnot will invalidate the order you took for granted.

**Typically, you would solve this by**

- Adding a dummy column to sort on *(if there's no reasonable existing column to pick)*
- Explicitly sort on that column

**Example**

```
SELECT 1 AS ToSortOn, ... FROM ...
UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS ToSortOn, ... FROM ...
ORDER BY ToSortOn
```

Comment: I think you are definitely right, I set the subno to 100 and done order by SUBNO, it worked...

Answer (score 2):

Although not the best method...

```
UNION ALL
```